# Loading Json File Into Highmaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm trying to load 2 Json files into Highmaps plugin.

- The firts one is the Map information (geometry)
- The second one is the data to be displayed

The second Json file structure is:

```
[{"code":"034","value":1},{"code":"036","value":1},{"code":"042","value":43},{"code":"045","value":18},{"code":"088","value":33},{"code":"120","value":3},{"code":"148","value":1},{"code":"154","value":3},{"code":"212","value":6},{"code":"250","value":1},{"code":"266","value":11},{"code":"308","value":4},{"code":"347","value":2},{"code":"360","value":6},{"code":"390","value":4},{"code":"001","value":147},{"code":"490","value":6},{"code":"579","value":1},{"code":"649","value":1},{"code":"736","value":1},{"code":"792","value":6},{"code":"837","value":10},{"code":"858","value":1},{"code":"890","value":4},{"code":"895","value":2}]
```

This is the JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/reo0kxk8/28/

Highmaps is not displaying the data.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? It is displaying in **Chrome** with some error.

For **Firefox**, it takes time to display.

I think the error is for not to access the json data, so test first from your local directory.  `format: '{point.properties.MPIO_CNMBR}'`. The code is not able to get the value of **MPIO_CNMBR**.

You missed the `data.js` file from the **Highmaps** Library.

Add the following one

`<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

```
 var data = [];
    $.getJSON("dataMap.json", function(json) {

            data=json;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/reo0kxk8/29/